# Can I carry 3 laptops from Mumbai to Bengaluru

Tags: air-travel, india, airport-security, mumbai, bangalore

For a particular work, I need to carry 3 laptops with me from Mumbai to Bangalore via flight. Will there be any problem in security check for carrying 3 laptops in local airport?

Comment: I have flown with 5 laptops between me and wife no issues

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question, as this is about a domestic flight whereas the other one is about an international flight. However it's not very clear what you are asking about: What exactly are you worried about or what makes you think that you cannot carry 3 laptops?

Comment: Customs is only for international travel; for intra-country travel - all you have to worry about is the weight limit.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to find this specific limitation on airline sites in India and I wasn't able to. If you are under the prescribed weight limit, I cannot foresee any problem with carrying 3 laptops in domestic flights.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem if you are travelling within India, if you are within weight limits of Cabin Baggage(Just that you have to get your laptop's out for security check).

Apart from Cabin Baggage Airlines allow carrying 1 separate Laptop [Jetairways](http://www.jetairways.com/EN/SG/TravelInformation/Baggage/cabin-baggage.aspx) & [Air India](http://www.airindia.in/hand-luggage.htm).

My suggestion check(Call them) with Airlines, if you can Check-in your laptops the Two/One of them.